# Keyboard hide not working on click

Tags: android, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch-2

In my application when i click the textfield the keyboard is showing, Up next the text field there is a button.On tap the button shows the actionsheet but the key board is not hiding,Actionsheet shows behind the keyboard

Here the code for actionsheet

```
   if (bval == "productpic") {
                if (!this.actions) {
                    this.actions = Ext.Viewport.add({
                        xtype: 'actionsheet',
                        style: 'background:#f3f3f3;',
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            ui: 'normal',
                            text: 'Take Photo',
                            scope: this,
                            handler: function () {
                                this.actions.hide();
                                capturePhoto();
                            }
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            ui: 'normal',
                            text: 'Choose Existing Photo',
                            scope: this,
                            handler: function () {
                                this.actions.hide();
                                getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);
                            }
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            ui: 'decline',
                            text: 'Cancel',
                            scope: this,
                            handler: function () {
                                this.actions.hide();
                            }
                        }]
                    });
                }
```

Manifest details

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
```

How to hide the key board on button tap in phonegap based android applciation?please help me out

Answer (score 0):

In the onCLick() event, put

> `InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
>         Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
>   imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);`

Where myEditText is the textfield causing the keyboard to show

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1)

Comment: Its not a native based application.its used javascript